# Cannot get label item (UI item) when running cypress headless in docker

Tags: docker, cypress

When running cypress with command

`npx cypress open` and `npx cypress run` (headless), it works fine.

But when I run cypress with docker (headless using cypress run), it hangs when trying to get label item.

```
cy.get('#label-page-id').then(($elPageId) => {
  cy.log('page id', elPageId);
});
```

I dont know why it does not work. Do I have to set something more so that docker knows.

Comment: Have you tried to use removing the `.then()` and using `.log()` directly?

Comment: I need to read the text in label, so I have to use `.then` and get label element. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Your code in your post only logs the found jquery element(s).